# Subscription Icon Not Showing in Embed View

Tags: tableau-api

Has anyone got any idea why the mail subscription icon is sometimes there and sometimes not?

If you log into the server and look at the report its always there but on the embedded one its only there if you have logged into the tableau server first.

In addition, has anyone a list of all possible options I can use in the code below?

```
var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");
var url = "https://mydomain/trusted/token/t/site/views/view?:embed=yes&:comments=no&:toolbar=yes&:tabs=yes";
var options = {
     hideTabs: false,
     width: "100%",
    height: "1000px"};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only subscribe if you exist as a user on Tableau Server because the subscription mail gets sent to the email address you have linked to that account. So, if you are not logged in you will not see the subscription icon.

Also, here is a list of all possible embed parameters: http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/help.htm#embed_list.htm

Comment: Sorry, I'll make it clearer. I go to my embedded view. No subscribe icon. I log into Tableau server - just log on, nothing else at all. I then refresh my embedded view and the subscribe icon appears. Why didn't it show ion the first place considering I used the REST API to authenticate already? Also I need the list of options like hideTabs/height/width and not embed paramters

Comment: If you look at the documentation link @emh provided, you'll see the following explanation for the :embed URL parameter -- "Hides the top navigation area, making the view blend into your web page better". Last I checked, the subscription icon was in the top navigation area. So you have a choice, use :embed to hide the Tableau icons or don't use :embed and show the Tableau icons. If you choose :embed, then you can use the Tableau APIs to define the behavior and appearance of the controls you want, except that I don't see that mail subscriptions made it into the APIs yet as of version 9.0